# Where are user defaults plist files stored in iOS8?

Tags: ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults, ios8

I can't find preferences .plist file, because Preferences folder is empty.
To get Library folder I use:

```
println(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0])
```

Xcode 6 beta 5, iOS Simulator

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The folder hierarchy has changed under iOS8.

All preferences are now stored under the common `/Library/Preferences` folder. Notice, this is not the `Library` folder under your app's container, it's the general `Library` folder.

For the simulator, the exact folder is:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/<Unique Simulator ID>/data/Library/Preferences
```

Comment: Another question why Apple does so? Unique Simulator ID, Unique App ID... Why so sophisticated?

Comment: Sophisticated? Because they don't want one simulator's files to merge with another. You can now have as many different simulators as you want, with the same OS.

Comment: I about names DD3CFE8A-9C8B-48FC-86F3-5E425FC70F87 - this is iPad 2 Simulator name, 854F49E0-EB3D-4FC7-8E17-A49E7CBDBD59 this is my app name... What advantage?

Comment: @ChikabuZ: Before Xcode 6, the simulator shared directories between different simulator instances. This meant that if you had an app and started it in both iPhone and iPad simulator, they accessed the same files which lead to problems that don't exist on real devices. I had to work around a few times, for example in an app that downloaded differently sized images depending on whether it ran on iPhone or iPad. With the new CoreSimulator and its separation, these problem are gone.

Comment: @ChikabuZ That's just UUID. It's not a name, it's a unique identifier

Comment: UUID is unique, while human readable names are not. You can name your simulator the same name, you can give it special characters that cannot appear in folder names. With UUID it's very simple.

Comment: @ChikabuZ: They are _unique_ and won't collide… it's an easy and good way to ensure that two different simulator instances will not interfere with each other. Even if you rename your simulator, the UUID will stay the same and the directory will not need to be renamed as well (which could again provoke a collision). From a technical point of view it's a good way. If you disagree you can tell Apple by filing a bug report.

Comment: @ChikabuZ: BTW, you can create symlinks with nice names to make it easier for you to distinguish them (as in, `ln -s DD3CFE8A-9C8B-48FC-86F3-5E425FC70F87 iPad2`).

Comment: @DarkDust: Thank you, after that I find a better way how to do this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory/LocalizingtheNameofaDirectory.html

Comment: UUID is not unique but rather "practically unique". Also, it's not that they wont collide, they rather "probably won't collide". You can read about UUID collision probability [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates) (spoiler) its very very small ;)